# Are SATA cables interchangeable?

Tags: power-supply

I just bought a new Seasonic Power Supply Unit.  It didn't come with enough SATA cables for my current setup, but I have some cables from previous power supplies (also Seasonics) that I've purchased.

Is it OK to use them with the new PSU?

UPDATE - I called Seasonic and the person I spoke to said I can not interchange them.  Not sure what to do besides order the cables

Comment: Can you post pictures of the cable ends and the spot on the drive you intend to plug it into? Typically, yes, any cable you get from a drive will work with other drives of the same type and any power cable that powered that drive will power a comparable drive just fine. It would still be better to post images if you have any doubts.

Comment: I compared them myself and they seem to match but there really is anything to distinguish between the power cables besides the fact that there is a different model number on them

Comment: AndyD, can you please provide model numbers of the PSUs and of the cables themselves?  Can you also take pictures of the connectors and ports, as @MaQleod suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Questions to consider:  What are you plugging the other end of the SATA cable into?  The power supply?  Does everything fit?

From my experience, people normally hang onto cables and connectors from older devices (of everything from phone chargers to VGA cables) because they usually come in handy in situations like what you have described.  As long as everything fits, and what you are plugging things into makes sense, it should be okay.

Comment: FYI - I've updated my post

Answer (score 0):

If the cables fit (the tips are very well standardized, so I would venture a guess that they will), you should be fine using them.

Answer (score 0):

It is Ok to check that they are wired the same or properly, for how you are going to use them.
It is likely from the same manufacture to be wired the same.
The Warning comes from people who assumed that all modular power connections are wired the same because the connection itself was the same, and fried something, it does not happen very often.
It takes only a few minutes to verify, by either checking the color coding, and it landing in the correct spots on the modular connection or with as cheap as a $5 voltage meter.
Other methods would be to check the manuels, or connection diagrams, or voltages, and follow non-color coded wiring down to see if it would land in the same places.
Another method is use that old hard drive the first time :-)